# Postfix on linux not sending mail

Tags: email, debian, postfix, email-server

For some reason my server has stopped sending mail, and I am not sure why.  I am running Debian 5.0 with postfix.  I remember setting it up using apt-get, and it worked fine.

Is there a config file that I need to update?  Can I send a test email from the shell?

Answer (score 18):

You should check your logfiles

```
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/daemon.log
```

It would be good to know if your mails are queued:

```
mailq
```

If there are mails in your queue try:

```
sendmail -q
```

Check your postfix service status:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix status
```

Please check your postfix configuration:

```
postfix check
```

Edit:

Please check your dns setup:

```
nslookup www.google.de
```

Please check if you are able to ping any of the destination domains:

```
ping www.google.de
```

Comment: Thanks, I see TONS of emails in the queue.  I am using google apps, and see these errors in the queue: delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com[72.14.213.27]:25: No route to host  (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.com[209.85.229.27]:25: Connection timed out)

Comment: Please check if your dns setup works - I've edited my post.

Answer (score 4):

Sending a test email from the shell can be accomplished with:

`echo "test-body" | mailx -s "test-subject" username@example.com`

You might need to `apt-get mailx` or so.

I'm not familiar with postfix, but maybe there's a log file in /var/log you can look at, or check /var/log/daemon.log.